# Variadic template, no matching function for call

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to use variadic template to refactor some of my code, but the compiler has "no matching function for call" error. Below is a simplified version (it may not make sense for functionality, but an example to reproduce the error):

```
// base case
void testFunc(int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }

template <class T, class... Args> void testFunc(int i) {
  T t = 0;
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
  testFunc<Args...>(i);
}

int main() {
  testFunc<int, long, float>(1);
  return 0;
}
```

The error messages:

```
main.cpp:9:3: error: no matching function for call to 'testFunc'
  testFunc<Args...>(i);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testFunc<float>' requested here
main.cpp:9:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testFunc<long, float>' requested here
main.cpp:13:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testFunc<int, long, float>' requested here
  testFunc<int, long, float>(1);
  ^
main.cpp:6:40: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
template <class T, class... Args> void testFunc(int i) {
                                       ^
1 error generated.
```

It looks like that the unwrapping of template parameters is working, and stops at the base case. But I have defined the base case. Why there is no matching function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that calling

```
testFunc<Args...>(i);
```

you call the template version of `testFunc()`, not the base case version.

And when `Args...` is empty, there isn't a template version available.

To solve this problem... if you can use C++17, you can use `if constexpr`, as suggested by YSC.

For C++11 and C++14, I propose to use the template partial specialization of a `struct`.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

// base case  
template <typename...>
struct foo
 { static void bar (int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; } };

// recursive case
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct foo<T, Args...>
 {
   static void bar (int i)
    {
      std::cout << T{} << std::endl;

      foo<Args...>::bar(i);
    }
 };

int main()
 {
   foo<int, long, float>::bar(1);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

For a single type, your function is not well-defined since it tries to call `void testFunct<>(int)` which differ from `void testFunc(int i)`.

You could test the size of your parameter pack before recursing using C++17's `constexp if`:

```
template <class T, class... Args> void testFunc(int i) {
  T t = 0;
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
  if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) > 0) {
    testFunc<Args...>(i);
  } else {
    testFunc(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: nice but, IMHO, you should specify that `if constexpr` is available starting from C++17

Comment: @max66 your answer did that. Together I think we provide a good set of complementary answers. I'm fine with it.

Comment: well... the problem I see is readers reading only your solution; anyway, you should also add the else case where is called `testFunc(i)` (the base, no template, case) otherwise your code doesn't print the `i` value.

Comment: @max66 true, fixed

Comment: The code in "A Tour of C++" "5.6. Variadic Templates" doesn't work. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As explained before the problem comes from the fact that `testFunc<int>(int i)` tries to call `testFunct<>(int t)`

However in C++ `testFunct<>(int t)` is different from `testFunct(int t)`

Also note that in C++ you can **not** partially specialize **functions**, as explained [here](https://artofsoftware.org/2012/12/20/c-template-function-partial-specialization/) for instance.

One solution that is close to your approach is to define

```
// Stop recursion
template <class T>
void testFunc(int i)
{
  T t = 0;
  std::cout << t << " " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}
```

and to avoid ambiguous definition thanks to [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

```
// instantiated only when Args... is not "empty"
template <class T, class... Args>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args)>::type testFunc(int i)
{
  T t = 0;
  std::cout << t << " " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
  testFunc<Args...>(i);
}
```

This is perfectly legal C++11 and it follows closely your initial guess

---

**Complete running code:** to compile with `g++ -std=c++11 testVariadic.cpp; ./a.out`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
void testFunc(int i)
{
  T t = 0;
  std::cout << t << " " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

template <class T, class... Args>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args)>::type testFunc(int i)
{
  T t = 0;
  std::cout << t << " " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
  testFunc<Args...>(i);
}

int main()
{
  testFunc<int, long, float>(1);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 i
0 l
0 f
```

Comment: This compiles for me with gcc but not clang.